# Can't make a new instance of a custom document library

Tags: document-library, feature, list-template

I am following the instructions of Cory Roth on how to create a custom document library in 2010 which can be found here http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/06/11/how-to-create-a-custom-document-library.aspx

I follow all of the instructions and can see that my custom library is sitting in the C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES directory. But I simply cant figure out how I can make a new instance of that library type.

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

Comment: Have you activated the feature that contains your new library template?

Comment: This is where my limited knowledge is hindering me. When I try to create a feature for the item, I don't see anything I can add to the feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a custom List Definition in Visual Studio, you will normally have an Elements and a Schema file (and maybe custom forms, etc). When you create a feature, you should see your List Definition listed an an element you can add to your feature. If you don't see it in VS2010, you probably have the feature scoped incorrectly. List Definitions need to be Site scoped.

If you have correctly defined your feature, and it includes your List Definition, then when you deploy you should see it in the TEMPLATES\FEATURES folder, and within that folder you should see the supporting files for your List Definition.

If all this is correct, then when you activate your feature on a Site Collection, you should be able to see your List Definition from the picker dialog when creating a new list or library (unless the List Definition is flagged as Hidden). A hidden List Definition can only be created programatically.

Comment: Thanks Chris, your answer greatly helped me in the solution

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

If you can see your new feature in 14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES than all you need is to activate it. You can use PowerShell command (SharePoint 2010 console): 
Enable-SPFeature –Identity FolderName –url http://mysite
or STSADM : 
stsadm –o activatefeature –name FolderNAme –url http://mysite
Than try to create new DL from appeared template